# How to set the default typing character encoding in R on Windows?

Tags: r, windows, encoding

I am new to this website and I actively use R in my Master's thesis calculations. I work with Russian data and have to handle russian cyrillic letters a lot, but on Windows the problem is that it does not encode characters in UTF-8 by default. Let me show you an example:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="Russian")
Encoding(c("Руссгрэйн Холдинг","Сбербанк","Русал","Магнит","Северсталь"))
```

As an output, you will get 'unknown'.

This is a problem for me because many functions of the stringr package won't work.

What workarounds I have tried:

1) Dual-boot with Linux Mint as on linux I can work with cyrillic letters right away without setting locale etc..

2) As for a solely Windows solution, I can manually set `enc2utf8()` each time when manipulating strings, but this is tedious and requires extra operation.

All in all, I would like to get a solution in windows where I could type in utf8 encoding right away so that I would not have to use enc2utf8 each time.

There are no questions on stackoverflow directly addressing my problem (they mostly concern importing data tables with utf-8 encoded characters which is not my case).

Answer (score 0):

As for now, the best option for Windows 10 is to use enc2native each time when working with UTF-8 encoded strings. This also will benefit in case of an active usage of the RStudio's viewer. For example, the viewer sorts UTF-8 encoded column in 10 seconds, while if the column is encoded natively, it manages to sort the entire column in just 2 seconds (a table with +200000 rows).